# How to retrieve nested data using Javascript (Firebase Realtime Database)?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve the data from donation and display it in a table. I was able to retrieve the user data from Users and displayed it on a table. But now I don't know how I will be able to retrieve the data from donation.

This is my database structure in Firebase. Note: All of the data that was entered came from a mobile app created in Android Studio. [image]

This is the code that I made when retrieving the User data.

```
function AddAllITemsToTable(User) {
            id=0;
            tbody.innerHTML="";
            User.forEach(element => {
                AddItemToTable(element.uid, element.fullName, element.organization, element.contactPerson, element.contactNo, element.location, element.emailAddress, element.status);
            });
        }

        function GetAllDataRealtime() {
            const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users');

            onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => {
                var Users = [];

                snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {
                    Users.push(childSnapshot.val());
                });

                AddAllITemsToTable(Users);
            })

        }

        window.onload = GetAllDataRealtime;
```

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Apologies, this is my first time using Stack Overflow.

Comment: At first glance that code looks fine. What isn't working about the code you shared? ---- Also: recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure), as the way you nest donations under each user does not follow the guidance on [nesting data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#avoid_nesting_data) and [keeping your structure flat](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#flatten_data_structures).

Comment: The code above is the one I used in getting the data of he users. What i need to do is to do the same but only with the data inside donation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're calling `onValue` on `/Users`, you already get all data for all users and all of their donations. To process the donations in your code:

```
const dbRef = ref(database, 'Users');

onValue(dbRef,(snapshot) => {
    var Users = [];

    snapshot.forEach(userSnapshot => {
        Users.push(userSnapshot.val());
        userSnapshot.child("donation").forEach((donationSnapshot) => {
            console.log(donationSnapshot.key, donationSnapshot.val());
        });
    });

    AddAllITemsToTable(Users);
})
```

As I said in my comment, I recommend reading the Firebase documentation on [structuring data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data#best_practices_for_data_structure), as the way you nest donations under each user does not follow the guidance on nesting data and keeping your structure flat.

Comment: I'm getting an uncaught referenceError saying that "childSnapshot is not defined".

Comment: Ah yeah, I renamed the variable to make it clearer what data it's a snapshot off. I updated it in my answer.

Comment: How will I be able to display all of the donation data inside a table?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to display it. Thank you so much Sir!